# Cooking pot spawned and moved through commands not interactable

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In *Skyrim Special Edition*, I bought the kitchen in Solitude, and noticed the missing cooking pot.
Followed the instructions [here](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Proudspire_Manor) (to spawn and position the pot, it's under the bugs section), but the pot is not interactable.

Is there a way to fix, or are items spawned like that all "fake"?

Comment: Are you playing Anniversary Edition and have the latest Unofficial Patch?

Comment: yes, and no. Its working now tho, I exit and reentered the house a bunch of times and didnt work. But after some hours of gameplay its working all of suddem.